# finding a node location within a BST and adding it to the tree recursively

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree, nodes

So i have 3 methods 1 that adds a node to the binary tree using the traverseAdd method, and another method which finds the location of where a value would be placed within the tree based on its parent node. I would like to eliminate the traverseAdd method and use the findLocation method within the add method to add the new value to the BST.

```
 public void add(int val) {
            /*Adds a new node to the binary tree after traversing the tree and figuring out where it belongs*/
            Node nodeObjToAdd = new Node(val);

            if(root == null){
            //if node root is not null root = new node value
                root = nodeObjToAdd;
            }

            Node nodeTraversed = root;

            traverseAdd(nodeTraversed, nodeObjToAdd);
        }
    private void traverseAdd(Node node, Node nodeObjToAdd){
        /*Traverses tree and finds a place to add the node to be added by comparing values of the left child and right child of the
        * focus node*/
            if(nodeObjToAdd.value < node.value){
                if(node.leftChild == null){
                    node.leftChild = nodeObjToAdd;
                }
                else {
                    //if the val < the root.value set int he constructor
                    traverseAdd(node.leftChild, nodeObjToAdd);
                }
            }
            else if(nodeObjToAdd.value > node.value) {
                if (node.rightChild == null) {
                    node.rightChild = nodeObjToAdd;
                } else {
                    traverseAdd(node.rightChild, nodeObjToAdd);
                }
            }
        }
    public Node findNodeLocation(Node rootNode, int val) {
        /*returns where a the Node after which the value would be added.*/
            if(val < rootNode.value && rootNode.leftChild != null){
                return rootNode.leftChild;
            }
            if(val >= rootNode.value && rootNode.rightChild != null){
                return rootNode.rightChild;
            }
            else
                return this.root;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void add(int val) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(val);
    }
    Node cur = root;
    Node next = null;
    while (true) {
        next = findNodeLocation(cur, val);
        if (next != cur) {
            cur = next;         
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (val < cur.value) {
        cur.leftChild = new Node(val);
    } else {
        cur.rightChild = new Node(val);
    }
}
```

I think this should work

Comment: This function is creating double root nodes now.

Comment: Is there anyway to refactor the findNodelocation method i have so that it is recursive?

Comment: So pretty, much now i cant figure out why the add method is adding two different root nodes when invoked and if there is anyway to make the findNodeLocation recursive and still have the same function. Also, your answer breaks and goes into an infinite loop when more than 2 numbers are inputted.